# Alternating capital letters without if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to write code so every other letter, starting from the first, is capitalized. I am also trying to do it using chr() and ord(), not .upper().

```
def randomString(max_length: int) -> str:
    string = ""
    length = random.randint(1, max_length)  # randomly choose a string length
    for i in range(length):
        random_offset = random.randint(0, 25)
        char = chr(ord('a') + random_offset)
        string = string + char
    return string
```

So I was thinking of either trying a nested for loop to do so or using a slice looking like string[::2]. My problem is I can't figure out how to do use something like the slice function to change individual values of string[]. I also have the proper variable for converting from lowercase to uppercase looking like this:

```
diff = ord('a')-ord('A')
```

My attempts have looked like:

```
 def randomString(max_length: int) -> str:
    string = ""
    length = random.randint(1, max_length)  # randomly choose a string length
    for i in range(length):
        random_offset = random.randint(0, 25)
        char = chr(ord('a') + random_offset)
        string = string + char
    for i in range(0,length,2):
        string[i]=chr(ord(string[i])-diff)
    return string
```

I assume my issue here is something with the scope of string, but I can't figure out how to fix it. I have tried quite a few other variations and am totally stuck.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Python — you can't change them. So `string[i]=...` will raise an exception. You could instead make a list of characters and then join them together into a string at the end. You could also either append an lowercase or an uppercase depending on whether the index is odd or even and avoid the second loop altogether.

Comment: I suggest solving the problem using `.upper()` and `.lower()` first, so you aren't debugging your string iteration at the same time you're debugging your ASCII math.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
import random
def randomString(max_length: int) -> str:
    string = ""
    length = random.randint(1, max_length)  # randomly choose a string length
    for i in range(length):
        random_offset = random.randint(0, 25)
        char = chr(ord('a') + random_offset)
        string = string + char
    return string

def altCap(word):
  print(word)
  halfWord = word[::2].upper()
  otherHalf = word[1:][::2]
  newWord = ""
  for i in range(len(otherHalf)):
    newWord += halfWord[i]
    newWord += otherHalf[i]
  if len(halfWord) > len(otherHalf):
    newWord += halfWord[-1]
    
  print(newWord)

altCap(randomString(26))
```

First, we split the word into two halves with `[::2]` so that it alternates. Then, we capitalize one of these halves. Finally, with a for loop, we add them both into new String, and add the final letter if one is still left.

Random Outputs:

```
ndqtyyhggwrqqk
NdQtYyHgGwRqQk

agvvtpyrkbzmcwtovpnfmixnj
AgVvTpYrKbZmCwToVpNfMiXnJ

zntphcudklwqdtp
ZnTpHcUdKlWqDtP
```

Also, if you want the second, fourth, etc letters to be capitalized then simply do `.upper()` to `otherHalf`.

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further clarification or details :)

Comment: (im also not 100% sure if this answered your question so lmk if i missed something)

Comment: I appreciate the answer! This totally works and I understand what you did. However, I am trying to do it within that for-loop where I am building the string, without using if statements. With if statements the way you built your code totally works, but that isn't what I am trying to do here.

Comment: oh wait i didnt even realize i had an if statement in there hold on let me try to fix

Answer (score 0):

The comments above all point out your problem, you can use a list to do this, alternate assignments can be made, try this：

```
import random


def randomString(max_length: int) -> str:
    length = random.randint(1, max_length)  # randomly choose a string length
    string_lst = [""] * length

    string_lst[0::2] = [chr(random.randint(65, 90)) for _ in range(len(string_lst[0::2]))]
    string_lst[1::2] = [chr(random.randint(97, 122)) for _ in range(len(string_lst[1::2]))]
    return "".join(string_lst)


print(randomString(10))
```